# MySQL connection via Unix socket works with mysqli but not with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using MAMP 5.5.42 with PHP 5.6.7 on my Mac OS 10.11.3. The code snippet is as follows :

```
try{
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:8889;dbname=lacolshow_database;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

The code above raises no exception, but produces an empty PDO object.

If `localhost:8889` is replaced by just `localhost` in the code above, an exception is raised with message
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`.

If `localhost:8889` is replaced by `127.0.0.1` in the code above, an exception is raised with message
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`.

Any help appreciated.

**Update:** the connection works  if I use mysqli instead of PDO :

```
$mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'lacolshow_database', NULL, '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock');
```

Following the advice given in the second comment at http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php, I tried the following :

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=lacolshow_database;unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock';
$db = new PDO($dsn,'root', 'root');
```

but that fails too, producing an empty PDO object.

Answer (score 2):

The [`port` is going into distinct parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php), not into `host`. So it should be

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=8889;dbname=lacolshow_database;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
```

Note that you don't have to catch and var_dump an exception, PHP will show you it by itself

Comment: What you propose also yields an empty PDO object. Also, my PHP does not show those PDO exception by itself. If I don't add the try/catch stuff, when I request the page I get a blank page

Comment: If you want errors to be shown,  you have to turn display errors on in your php.ini

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about that

Comment: ... Or I can also put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the start of my php code, right ?

Comment: error_reporting is another thing. you have to have it either way but to display errors you have to add `ini_set('display_errors',1);` if you want it in the code

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You need to add the port number in the connection string to connect with your DB. Your DB server is running at port no.: `8889` in your local environment, so `localhost:8889` used in DB connection string **will not raise any exception.**

**2)** If you replace `localhost:8889` by `localhost` then the connection will not establish and an error with message `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`  will occur that indicates  a MySQL connection via socket is tried (**which is not supported**).

**3)** When you use `127.0.0.1` a connection attempt will be made but will be refused, `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused.` It means the SQL database was either offline or being accessed incorrectly.  **Perhaps an incorrect port or socket path.**

Hence, the first point is correct way to establish a connection with DB server.